# WPF Toolkit Charts don't show if I change the ControlTemplate of a DataPoint in .NET 4

Tags: charts, tooltip, wpftoolkit, controltemplate

I am experiencing a very weird problem with the WPF Toolkit Charts in a .NET 4 environment. 
Basically, I just want to customize the ToolTip template for ColumnDataPoints. To accomplish that, I copied the default style for a ColumnDataPoint from the toolkit source code (generic.xaml) into my control resources and changed the TooltipService part like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="charts:ColumnDataPoint" x:Key="CustomDataPointStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charts:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" x:Name="Root">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.6" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#77ffffff" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#ccffffff" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border BorderBrush="#77ffffff" BorderThickness="1" />
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Fill="White" Opacity="0" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentControl Content="Custom ToolTip" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now, the problem is that as soon as I apply my CustomDataPointStyle (even if I don't change anything!), the ColumnSeries doesn't show at all in my chart.

```
<Grid x:Name="ChartGrid" DataContext="{Binding}">
<charts:Chart x:Name="Chart1" Margin="5,0,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                       
    Title="{Binding Path=Title}">
    <charts:Chart.Axes>
        <charts:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Title="{Binding Path=XAxisTitle}" Location="Bottom" />
        <charts:CategoryAxis Orientation="Y" Title="{Binding Path=YAxisTitle}" Location="Right" ShowGridLines="True" />
    </charts:Chart.Axes>

    <charts:ColumnSeries x:Name="ColumnSeries" Title="{Binding Path=SeriesTitle}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource CustomDataPointStyle}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}">
    </charts:ColumnSeries>
</charts:Chart>
```

results in this:

[image]

I guess that I am missing a VisualState or something that actually renders the chart but how can that be, given that I copied(!) the original style? The Toolkit is made for .NET 3.5 and I have to use .NET 4 in my application - could that be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear, I found the answer: I replaced the System.Windows.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll for .NET 3.5 with the 4.0 version [of this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/22/nobody-likes-a-show-off-today-s-datavisualizationdemos-release-includes-new-demos-showing-off-stacked-series-behavior.aspx) and now it's working!

Comment: Yes, I solved the same issue by replacing `System.Windows.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll`

Answer (score 1):

You could also try setting Opacity="1" in your Border style block:

`<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="1" x:Name="Root">`